# Redirect 301 com Webconfig

Tags: htaccess, web.config

Uso uma regra que funciona mais não me parece correta. Acho que acaba dando dois redirect 301.

```
            <!--Forçar https-->
            <rule name="Https" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="https" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="false" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{URL}" />
            </rule>
            <!--Forçar Www-->
            <rule name="Www" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="^(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                  <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(site\.com\.br)(:80)?" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://www.site.com.br/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

O primeiro é para forçar o https e o segundo forçar o www. Como monto uma só regra que faça as duas coisas. Tem que ser no web.config mesmo.